# How do you make an API private (ie. it can only be accessed from the frontend, people can't write their own python script/postman api call(

Tags: security, next.js, cookies, jwt

Right now I'm building a React Next.js web app with JWT for authentication and I'm not sure how to make certain API calls only accessible from the frontend. I store my JWT in cookies with HTTP only and secure as true and fetch the cookies from the backend for authentication. But I realized that even with these settings, it can be accessed by the client:
[image]
Using this token, I can then make an API call by setting the headers Cookie "token=...". The HTTP endpoint responds normally and sends back the data:
[image]
Is there a way to make it so that people, even the actual user who logged into their own account, can't access the API through their own scripts?

Some things I thought about were:

1. API key: If I store API Key in .env, it can only be accessed as NEXT_PUBLIC_APIKEY, which I would assume gives clients access as well.
2. Encrypting the JWT. Same problem, I can't decrypt the cookie on the frontend without exposing the private key. On the other hand, if I decrypt on the backend, then people can just send a request with the encrypted token.

I heard the rate limiting + short token expiry and IP whitelisting are solutions. Would these be viable solutions? Also, what's the standard solution? By the way, does Auth0 make HTTP endpoints private?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a little confused on how JWT-based authentication works. Here's a rundown:

1. You generate a 32-byte (minimum) secure string that only the server knows. Let's call it JWT_SECRET.
2. The user logs in, you make a request to ORM/DB to validate their login credentials.
3. You create a JWT payload object that contains their basic contact information, and possibly roles, groups, etc.
4. You sign and encrypt that payload using the JWT_TOKEN. I personally use the `jose` library to handle this. It's a nice pure JS JWT package
5. You set the JWT encrypted payload as an HTTP-only secure cookie

Now, on subsequent requests, you use JWT_SECRET to run `jwtVerify` which 1.) validates that the cookie has not been altered, and 2.) decodes the stored user information. You can store information like roles and groups to determine route access and to incorporate into your business logic, but you need a way to invalidate and recreate the token when these parameters change. This is really nice because it reduces loads on the database, Redis, etc and allows you to run these checks in middleware, which needs to remain very fast.

You NEVER expose your JWT_SECRET to the client, so you don't use the NEXT_PUBLIC prefix. A user cannot forge a token because they don't know the key. If they tried to encode a JWT using a different key, then it would fail jwtVerify. See, you can decode JWTs without the signing key, but they will fail verification if they are not signed with the same key.

Now, it's not impossible to crack JWT signatures or for an attacker to possibly forge a JWT, so sometimes it's not always best to rely on the JWT alone for access control. I personally like to make a database request for certain functions. But that's totally up to you.

Also, if you want to store user data (like for their public profile display), you can set a separate cookie containing their unencrypted public information. Or you could use localstorage or indexed DB. I actually created my own React context that allows me to have a Redis-style API for the indexed DB. I can give you the code if you want.

I actually wrote an in-depth blog article on JWT authentication in Next.js. Please feel free to check it out. There's also a link to a GitHub starter app you can check out for code examples:

https://blog.designly.biz/a-complete-guide-to-authentication-in-next-js-14